# Idiomatic way to port C bitfiddling to Python

Tags: python, c, bit-manipulation

How would you port the following C code in a Pythonic way (especially the bit fiddling part in Get2, Get3, ...)

```
switch(mem[pos-1])
{
  ...
  case 0x10: pos+=Get2(&mem[pos+0x02])+0x04; break;
  case 0x11: pos+=Get3(&mem[pos+0x0F])+0x12; break;
  case 0x16: pos+=Get4(&mem[pos+0x00])+0x04; break;
  ...
  case 0x20: pos+=0x02; break;
}

...

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Conversion routines to fetch bytes in Big Endian order
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

unsigned int Get2(unsigned char *pointer)
{
  return (pointer[0] | (pointer[1]<<8));
}

unsigned int Get3(unsigned char *pointer)
{
  return (pointer[0] | (pointer[1]<<8) | (pointer[2]<<16));
}

unsigned int Get4(unsigned char *pointer)
{
  return (pointer[0] | (pointer[1]<<8) | (pointer[2]<<16) | (pointer[3]<<24));
}
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
    x = struct.unpack('B', mem[pos-1])[0]

    if x == 0x10:
        # pos += ???
        continue

    if x == 0x11:
        # pos += ???
        continue

    if x == 0x16:
        # pos += ???
        continue

    if x == 0x20: 
        pos += 0x02
        continue
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you provide an example of input and your expected output? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just getting one unsigned byte, just do

```
x = ord(mem[pos - 1])
```

on Python 2 or

```
x = mem[pos - 1]
```

on Python 3.

Instead of select / case, You want a dictionary.

```
positions = {0x10: do_10, 0x11: do_12, 0x16: do_16}
```

Where `do_10` etc. are functions:

```
def do_10(pos):
    # This actually would need an endianness character
    return struct.unpack('H', mem[pos + 0x02])[0] + 0x04
```

You use it like this:

```
pos += positions[mem[pos - 1]](pos)
```

If you want to define the functions right in the dictionary, you can:

```
positions = {
    # This actually would need an endianness character
    0x10: (lambda pos: struct.unpack('H', mem[pos + 0x02])[0] + 0x04)
    # ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but based on your code, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
x = struct.unpack('B', mem[pos-1])[0]
if x == 0x10:
    pos += 0x04 + struct.unpack('>h' mem[pos+0x04])
elif x == 0x11:
    pos += 0x12 + (0x00FFFFFF & struct.unpack('>i' mem[pos+0x0F]))
elif x == 0x16:
    pos += 0x04 + struct.unpack('>i' mem[pos])
elif x == 0x20: 
    pos += 0x02
```

Comment: Thanks! Needs some tweaking but surely in the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your four bit-fiddlers could almost transliterated in python

```
def bigstr_to_int2(str) :
    return (ord(str[0])<<8) | ord(str[1])
```

Seems to work, but is perhaps not "idiomatic".  Ideally, you should try to use the struct.unpack to do the whole thing in bulk, but I can't tell you how to do that, because I don't understand the main function up the top.